# Delaying New Unread Email Count Notification in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

How can you delay the unread message count notification appearing in Outlook 2013?  I get a lot of emails that I filter using Outlook's rules and third-party software.  However these emails still come in every few minutes causing the new unread email count to increase on the Inbox folder while they are being processed which can take a couple of minutes.  This causes a distraction from what I am doing.  I would still like to see the new unread email count increase for emails which make it through my email filter.  Is is possible to delay the new unread email count from appearing say until after the email is in the inbox for 2 minutes, and, if so, how can it be done?  Delaying the notification a couple minutes should let most of the junk email get filtered without me being distracted by the new unread email count notification updating.

Thanks, 
Michael

Answer (score -1):

Minimize your Outlook when you need to work undistracted?